# fitBounds does not center correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I initialize the map I add 1 marker to the map. When I zoom the map out I can see the added marker multiple times on the map 'copies'.
[image: zoomed out map with multiple markers visible]

When I then search for a location the map it adds a new marker.
After that I use fitBounds to fit the two markers on the map.

Normally this would result in the following:
[image: Normally functioning fitBounds]

But **sometimes** it does this:
[image: Incorrect centering of fitBounds]

I have the feeling the fitBounds method **sometimes** uses the marker on *'the other world'*.
The latitude and longitude for both markers are correct and as you can see there *are* now 2 markers on the left.

Can someone please explain to me why this happens and how I can avoid/fix it?

Here is a part of the search submit function where I calculate the bounds:

```
var searchResultLocation = mapSearchPlaces[0].geometry.location;

//Create search marker
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: searchResultLocation,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    map: map
});
searchMarkers.push(marker);

//Find map bounds
var closestMarker = null;
var closest = Number.MAX_VALUE;
for (var i=0; i < markerLocations.length; i++) {
    var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(searchResultLocation, markerLocations[i]);
    if (distance < closest) {
        closest = distance;
        closestMarker = markerLocations[i];
    }
}
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(searchResultLocation, closestMarker);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) constructor take two very specific arguments, in a specific order:

```
  LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng, ne?:LatLng) | Constructs a rectangle from the points at its south-west and north-east corners.
```

You should create an empty LatLngBounds object and *extend* it with the two points:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(searchResultLocation);
bounds.extend(closestMarker);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```